# Derived app in omnet++ from UDPBasicApp not registered or linked in

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to implement my own UDP app from inet's UDPBasicApp. I have created a VoIPApp.cc that looks like this:

```
#include <omnetpp.h>

class VoIPApp: public inet::UDPBasicApp {
public:

};

Register_Class(VoIPApp);
```

I declare the app in my network.ned file:

```
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.FlatNetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;
import ned.DatarateChannel;
import inet.applications.udpapp.UDPBasicApp;

simple VoIPApp extends UDPBasicApp
{
    @class(VoIPApp);
}

network VoIPNetwork
{
    @display("bgb=561,272");
    types:
        channel standardChannel extends DatarateChannel
        {
            delay = default(10ms);
            datarate = default(10Mbps);
        }
    submodules:
        host1: StandardHost {
            @display("p=108,96");
        }
        host2: StandardHost {
            @display("p=431,96");
        }
        flatNetworkConfigurator: FlatNetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=253,31");
        }
        host3: StandardHost {
            @display("p=250,221");
        }
    connections:
        host1.pppg++ <--> standardChannel <--> host2.pppg++;
        host1.pppg++ <--> standardChannel <--> host3.pppg++;
        host3.pppg++ <--> standardChannel <--> host2.pppg++;
}
```

And I set at least one of the three StandardHost nodes to use this app in omnetpp.ini:

```
[General]
network = VoIPNetwork

repeat = 1
sim-time-limit = 100s
**.networkConfiguratorModule = ""

#Measure
**.ppp[*].numInputHooks = 1 
**.ppp[*].inputHook[0].typename = "ThruputMeter" 
**.vector-recording = false


# Client settings
**.host1.numUdpApps = 1 
**.host1.udpApp[0].typename = "VoIPApp"  
**.host1.udpApp[0].destAddresses = "host2 host3" 
**.host1.udpApp[0].destPort = 5000
**.host1.udpApp[0].localPort = 5000
**.host1.udpApp[0].messageLength = 32B + 40B #Data: 32B, Header: 40B = 20B(IP) + 8B(UDP) + 12B(RTP)
**.host1.udpApp[0].sendInterval = 20ms # 1000ms / 20ms = 50 packets per second.

**.host2.numUdpApps = 1 
**.host2.udpApp[0].typename = "UDPBasicApp"  
**.host2.udpApp[0].destAddresses = "host1 host3" 
**.host2.udpApp[0].destPort = 5000
**.host2.udpApp[0].localPort = 5000 
**.host2.udpApp[0].messageLength = 32B + 40B
**.host2.udpApp[0].sendInterval = 20ms

**.host3.numUdpApps = 1 
**.host3.udpApp[0].typename = "UDPBasicApp"  
**.host3.udpApp[0].destAddresses = "host1 host2" 
**.host3.udpApp[0].destPort = 5000
**.host3.udpApp[0].localPort = 5000 
**.host3.udpApp[0].messageLength = 32B + 40B
**.host3.udpApp[0].sendInterval = 20ms
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Error in module (omnetpp::cModule) VoIPNetwork.host1 (id=2) during network setup: Class "VoIPApp" not found -- perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module()/Define_Channel().
```

I have also tried using Define_Module() instead of Register_Class(), resulting in the same error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where do you place `VoIPApp.cc` and ` VoIPApp.ned` files - in separate project or in INET `src/inet/applications/udpapp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had created the project using the IDE: `New -> Project`. This is not the same as `New -> New OMNeT++ Project`.

I guess it was missing some essential OMNeT++ stuff. The devil is in the details.

After creating a proper omnet project, VoIPApp.cc can then just include `<UDPBasicApp.h>`:

```
#include <UDPBasicApp.h>

class VoIPApp: public UDPBasicApp {
public:

};

Define_Module(VoIPApp);
```

And also you should place the declaration of VoIPApp not in the standard package.ned but in its own VoIPApp.ned:

```
package voip;

import inet.applications.udpapp.UDPBasicApp;

simple VoIPApp extends UDPBasicApp {
    @class(VoIPApp);
}
```

Note that I am required to run OMNeT++ 4.6 and inet 2.6 instead of the latest versions and thus the include paths of the NED file correspond to paths of these versions now.

Comment: Could you explain how you build your project created without OMNeT++ support? Do you prepare own makefile by hand or using opp_makemake? What is the result of compilation - a library or an executable file?

Comment: As you have mentioned, you have created the project without OMNeT++ support (i.e. New > project instead of New > OMNeT++ project) I'm not sure the reason why... This means that the IDE will not generate the makefile automatically and you are on your own to manage your project, inter project dependency, include directory, library path and everything else. The error you've received could be because of a lot of things. Primarily after adding a .cc file you ALWAYS have to run the opp_makemake to re-create the makefile from scratch. My suggestion, use the IDE support... (OMNeT++ project)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear: creating the project through New > Project was part of my error. The above code only works if you create a proper omnet project.